# With file I/O in Java, how do I only use a particular set of data within a text file with different data?

Tags: java, file-io

I am working on a problem for my beginning Java class. I cannot find a *specific* answer for this kind of case, but I did see some answers about reading individual lines, general file I/O, and printing a set of data from inside a file.

A lot of the answers use things which are out of the scope of my course and don't really give me a solid idea as to what to do. In short, what I need to do is take the middle column of a text file only and use that data to compute and then print an average in the main class of the program.

The data in the middle is all doubles, but the program is somehow counting the integers on the left? I specifically said `input.nextDouble();` so I'm pretty confused here. Doubles have higher precedence than ints, but why would these ints be counted as doubles? This may actually be very simple, but I'm not sure how I messed up.

Here is the code that I've typed so far for what I am trying to accomplish:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HouseHold {

    public void displayFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("Program10.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        System.out.printf("%s   %s   %s%n%n", "ID#", "Yearly Income", "# of Occupants");
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            System.out.printf("%-10d %10.2f   %-10d %n", input.nextInt(), input.nextDouble(), input.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
        input.close();
    }

    //double
    public void averageIncome() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("Program10.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        int numMuns = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {

            numMuns++;
            sum += input.nextDouble();

            //The next two lines are how I found the issue:
            System.out.println(numMuns);
            System.out.println(sum);

        }

    }



        //return sum / numMuns;
}
```

I actually had to copy the data from the .txt file below into Microsoft Excel in order to make sure I was right. I'm glad I did, because it was *dramatically* different:

```
1042  12180.06  3
1062  13240.45  2
1327  19800.56  2
1483  22458.23  7
1900  17000.09  3
2112  18125  4
2345  15623  2
3210   3200  1
3600  39500  5
3601  11970  2
4724   8900  3
6217  45000.70  2
9280   6200  1
1000  31000  3
1200  36000  2
5601  51970  9
5724  66900  3
5217  10002.68  2
5280  70000  1
5000 100000  6
5200  25000.4  3
5230 120000  6
6641  85000  7
7000  45500  4
7100  56500  3
8110 110005.9  8
9101  67590.40 6
```

I've already formatted the file data and have it displayed in the main class (which is another specification for this project):

```
ID#     Yearly Income   # of Occupants

1042         12180.06   3          
1062         13240.45   2          
1327         19800.56   2          
1483         22458.23   7          
1900         17000.09   3          
2112         18125.00   4          
2345         15623.00   2          
3210          3200.00   1          
3600         39500.00   5          
3601         11970.00   2          
4724          8900.00   3          
6217         45000.70   2          
9280          6200.00   1          
1000         31000.00   3          
1200         36000.00   2          
5601         51970.00   9          
5724         66900.00   3          
5217         10002.68   2          
5280         70000.00   1          
5000        100000.00   6          
5200         25000.40   3          
5230        120000.00   6          
6641         85000.00   7          
7000         45500.00   4          
7100         56500.00   3          
8110        110005.90   8          
9101         67590.40   6
```

The problem that I've discovered is that the ID# is being put into the average as well.

The ID# is an int. The incomes are doubles. The method `averageIncome()` is supposed to return a double equal to the average `(sum / numMuns)`, but, as I've said, it doesn't. Any suggestions? I may be overlooking something, but I'd appreciate some help. Thanks!

EDIT-
Here is what I've done to try and fix this, but there are still serious issues that I'm having trouble fixing:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HouseHold {

    public void displayFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("Program10.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        System.out.printf("%s   %s   %s%n%n", "ID#", "Yearly Income", "# of Occupants");
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            System.out.printf("%-10d %10.2f   %-10d %n", input.nextInt(), input.nextDouble(), input.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
        input.close();
    }

    //double
    public void averageIncome() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("Program10.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        int numMuns = 0;
        double sum = 0.0;
        do {
            String inputRead = input.nextLine();
            String[] line = inputRead.split("  ");
            sum += Double.parseDouble(line[1]);
            /*
            if(inputRead.contains(".")) {
                //System.out.println(inputRead);
                sum += Double.parseDouble(inputRead);
                numMuns++;
                System.out.println(numMuns);
                System.out.println("\n" + sum);
            }
            */

        } while (input.hasNext());

        System.out.println(numMuns);
         //return sum / numMuns;

    }


}
```

An exception is thrown when I get to the part that I need to debug:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "67590.40 6"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at program10.HouseHold.averageIncome(HouseHold.java:32)
    at program10.TestHouseHold.main(TestHouseHold.java:13)
```

The issue, as far as I can tell, is that it can't parse the data of the original file due to the scattered format. As much as I would love to fix the .txt file, I can't modify it because the instructor will not give me a good grade if I modify it (he compiles and runs the code with the original file(s) he provided for the assignment). Perhaps I could try to parse it without delimiters? The spacing in the original file is not amenable to simple String splitting apparently. Additionally, I think I need to format some of the dollar amounts into doubles because the if statement isn't seeing them (. is not in all- some are just written as ints). 
I'll look up some more possible solutions too, but any further ideas or guidance would be much appreciated!

FINAL EDIT:
The issue has been resolved via the explanation provided below by KID94. It was much simpler than I thought. Thanks for all the help, guys!

Comment: [`nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) does not mean "search for the next value that looks like a double value". Javadoc says: *"Scans the **next token** of the input as a double. This method will throw `InputMismatchException` if the next token cannot be translated into a valid double value"*. All values are parse-able as a double, so it reads *all* the values.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. That's very helpful. I need to learn how to read the javadoc, but it requires me to know a great deal more of the language to be able to be more useful. It doesn't teach, it just gives developers a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple since you had already known that the first column and the last column are all integers, just use `input.nextInt()` to pass them before and after reading the middle column, like this:

```
public double averageIncome() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("Program10.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    int numMuns = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (input.hasNext()) {

        numMuns++;

        // Just read id and ignore it
        input.nextInt();

        sum += input.nextDouble();

        // Just read # of Occupants and ignore it
        input.nextInt();

        //The next two lines are how I found the issue:
        System.out.println(numMuns);
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
    return sum / numMuns;
}
```

Comment: OH! Thank you so much, man! This actually works! You're a hero! I guess I can mark this as the solution since it returned the ~correct answer (we don't learn how to do better financial calculations in this course, so it isn't 100% because of truncation, but this should work). Wow, it was that simple... Thanks again!

Comment: "we don't learn how to do better financial calculations in this course", FYI, if needed, you can use `java.math.BigDecimal`, it's much more precise, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're trying to take just the middle item from each line and average those together.

One approach would be to tokenize each line into an array of elements and then grab just the middle element.

I would replace:

```
sum += input.nextDouble();
```

with:

```
String line = input.nextLine();
String[] tokens = line.split(" ") //You can replace the blank space with whatever it is that is separating each entry in the line. its hard to tell what that is from the original post
sum += Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
```

Comment: Apparently, my instructor did not put a delimiter in the file. I have tried your solution and... java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String at...Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source). Probably because it reads the whole line and then it can't do anything with it.

Comment: Additionally, I just found that there are two spaces between the ID# and one space between the # of occupants. That's in the original file which is formatted in a very scattered way for no apparent reason.

So, when I use two spaces as a delimiter, the same exception is thrown because the # of occupants is only 1 space away. The file is formatted stupidly either because a) he wants us to figure out how to fix it or b) he overlooked this problem. I am very frustrated at this point.

Comment: Oh, to make matters more difficult, our instructor told us not to modify files in the project other than the classes we are told to code. He said he'd run it with the original files and if it doesn't work, well, we don't pass that assignment. I'm stumped. If you look at the original file in my question, you'll see what I mean about how the file is so scattered. I formatted the output, but the original file is just...ugh. Not sure what to do. I may email him or something, but nobody else has said anything about this in my class...

Comment: Try using " +" as a delimiter. That is a pattern for one or more spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    int x = 0;
    double y = 0.0;
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
   //using regex and splitting the line at one or more whitespaces taking the second value and parsing it as double
        y += Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+")[1]);
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println(y);
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y / x);
```

Comment: we didn't go over the BufferedReader object. He said that it'd be in the intermediate course. I think I can see what you are doing, but I don't think he'd like me to jump ahead (as much as I'd like to take the easy way out sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

Jamey input.nextDouble will try to scan the next input in as a double. this is why all of your numbers are being included in the sum.(See Link Below)
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextdouble.htm

As for a solution to your issue I would read the the input as a string, and use the decimal as an indicator that the string is a double. If it has a decimal convert the string to a double and add it to your sum.

```
 File file = new File("program10.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        int numMuns = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {

            numMuns++;
            String inputToRead =  input.next();
            if(inputToRead.contains(".")) {

                sum += Double.parseDouble(inputToRead);
            }

            //sum += input.nextDouble();

            //The next two lines are how I found the issue:
            //System.out.println(numMuns);

    }
```

Comment: The following exception occurred when I tried your solution (your solution seems plausible, though):

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at program10.HouseHold.averageIncome(HouseHold.java:32)
 at program10.TestHouseHold.main(TestHouseHold.java:13)

Comment: Jamey sorry I did not notice you were using a do while. Despite having a solution I thought I would just edit my post to be more clear.